# Handle expired Facebook access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, access-token

I'm working on a Windows Phone 8.1 application which has relies on the services provided by Facebook. It is not using any `FacebookClient` or any other Facebook NuGet packages.

I wasn't able to find out exactly how the validity of an access token should be handled. In other words, I am having an access token from sometime in the past, and I still want to see if I can use it now or the user should authenticate and get a new one.

As I searched over the poor Facebook documentation, they suggest ([here, at **App Tokens** section](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens?locale=ro_RO#apptokens)) that a way to do this is to send a request along with the **AppSecret**.

They also advice :

*"Note that because this request uses your app secret, it must never be made in client-side code or in an app binary that could be decompiled. It is important that your app secret is never shared with anyone. Therefore, this API call should only be made using server-side code."*

Which is quite understandable.

But since I am making direct calls to Facebook from client to server, does this still apply in the case of a Windows Phone app? (Or after all, I guess even Android or Iphone app)

How should this be handled, in a manner that the AppSecret isn't exposed?

Comment: Just make any request to the graph api. You will get an error message back if the access token is expired

Answer (score 0):

You can either make any simple request to the Graph API, and if the Access Tokenn is invalid, you'll receive an error from the Graph API, or call

`GET /debug_token?input_token={input-token}&access_token={access-token}`

where

- `{input_token}`: the access token you want to get information about
- `{access_token}`: your app access token or a valid user access token from a developer of the app

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#debug

Comment: You gave me the same link :)

Comment: I have read that already, the problem was getting the App Access Token. This required a server to server call in order not to expose the app secret. My client app would make calls to server and that would potentially expose the AppSecret. Anyhow, I went to make a check call with the saved Access Token and if it fails, the users are redirected to authenticate again.

Comment: Yes, but another section of it, and another call. You're right about the app access token security though. You could write a backend service which just takes the User Access Token supplied by your app, then adds the app Access Token, send the request to FB, and pipes back the result to the request your app was sending.